# Add TextBlock inside Button template

Tags: windows-phone-7, templates, button, textblock

I created a custom style for my buttons which looks like this:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CustomButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#464646" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonNumber">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonCharacters">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonNumber">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonCharacters">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="0">
                            <Canvas>
                                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                <TextBlock Margin="23,14,0,0" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" FontSize="48" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" x:Name="ButtonNumber" Text="XXX" />
                                <TextBlock Margin="54,36,0,0" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" FontSize="18" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" x:Name="ButtonCharacters" Text="YYY" />
                            </Canvas>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

As you can see I added two new TextBlocks inside the button (`ButtonNumber` and `ButtonCharacters`). Now I want to use a custom value for the `Text` properties of those two TextBlocks (marked with XXX and YYY), so that it looks something like that:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}" ButtonNumber.Text="123" ButtonCharacters.Text="SomeText" />
```

I have no clue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better would be inherit Button class, add two dependency properties (Text1 and Text2, for example) and  to that class (let's call it TextButton for a while).

Then, set generic template (in /themes/generic.xaml) for TextButton and inside ControlTemplate  you can use following markup

```
      <TextBlock x:Name="ButtonNumber" Text="{TemplateBinding Text1}" />
      <TextBlock x:Name="ButtonCharacters" Text="{TemplateBinding Text2}" />
```

That would be easiest and best-practice way.

Comment: I haven't done this until now. So do you have a link oder tutorial for this? Thank you!

Comment: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Creating-a-WP7-Custom-Control-in-7-Steps
Use that guide for basic overview.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be what I need!